# Karma / PhantomJS cannot run unittests written in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, systemjs

I'm trying to get my unittests running in phantomJS using Karma & Jasmine. The unittests are written in Typescript, as well as the source files. 
**The tests run *fine* in Chrome, Safari & Firefox**, but fail in PhantomJS. 
The error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: (SystemJS) eval@[native code]
        tryCatchReject@/poc/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js:1188:34
        runContinuation1@/poc/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js:1147:18
        when@/poc/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js:935:20
        run@/poc/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js:826:17
        _drain@/poc/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js:102:22
        drain@/poc/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js:67:15
        Evaluating /poc/src/components/button/button.js
        Error loading /poc/test/components/button/button.spec.ts
```

I've tried to hook up the phantomjs debugger, but it does not throw any error, so I'm kinda stuck here.

Karma config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    customLaunchers: {
      'PhantomJS_custom': {
        base: 'PhantomJS',
        options: {
          windowName: 'my-window',
          settings: {
            webSecurityEnabled: false
          }
        },
        flags: ['--load-images=true'],
        debug: true
      }
    },

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['systemjs', 'jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-systemjs',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-remap-istanbul',
      'karma-typescript-preprocessor',
      'karma-safari-launcher',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.ts': ['typescript', 'coverage']
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
      'test/**/button.spec.ts',
      'testutils/**/*.ts'
    ],

    systemjs: {
      configFile: 'config/system.conf.js',
      config: {
        packages: {
          'src': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          'test': {
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
          },
          'testutils': {
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
          }
        },

        transpiler: "typescript"
      },

      serveFiles: [
        'src/**/*.ts',
        'test/**/button.spec.ts',
        'testutils/**/*.ts'
      ]
    },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        {
          type: 'json',
          dir: 'coverage',
          subdir: '.',
          file: 'report.json'
        }
      ]
    },

    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      src: 'coverage/report.json',
      reports: {
        lcovonly: 'coverage/lcov.info',
        html: 'coverage/html/report'
      }
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: [
      'progress',
      'coverage',
      'karma-remap-istanbul'
    ],
    typescriptPreprocessor: {
      // options passed to the typescript compiler
      options: {
        inlineSourceMap: true,
        inlineSources: true,
        "outDir": ".tmp/",
        sourceMap: false,
        noImplicitUseStrict: true,
        target: 'ES5', // (optional) Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), or 'ES5'
        module: 'commonjs', // (optional) Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd'
        concatenateOutput: false // (optional) Concatenate and emit output to single file. By default true if module option is omitted, otherwise false.
      }
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],//, 'Safari', 'Chrome', 'Firefox'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,

    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 20000000000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 0,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 1000000000
  })
};
```

Comment: `Error loading /poc/test/components/button/button.spec.ts`
Suggests that PhantomJS is loading the wrong files. Do the TypeScript preprocessor creates the `.js` files from `.ts` files?

Comment: Yes, the transpiled files are loaded (at least, they are in Safari / Chrome, I have no reason to believe that they aren't loaded in PhantomJS)

Comment: I remember there is some problem with `eval` in or `Date` in PantomJS.
Try to run simplest example